# Memory Issues with SKSprite Scenes

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, sprite-kit, skspritenode

When I try transitioning between two scenes, memory goes up.  No deallocation.  I try to call skView.removeFromSuperview() but screen goes black.  Here is my code:

```
func goGame()
{

    //crowdImage.hidden = true
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    scene?.removeAllActions()
    scene?.removeAllChildren()
    scene?.removeFromParent()
    //view.removeFromSuperview()
    if myviewbool == 0
    {

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.frameInterval = 2
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
            scene.viewController = self
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
        }
        skView2.scene?.removeFromParent()
        //skView2.removeFromSuperview() // CAUSES BLACK SCREEN
    }
    if myviewbool == 1
    {

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            skView2 = self.view as! SKView
            skView2.frameInterval = 2
            skView2.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
            scene.viewController = self
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView2.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))

        }
        skView.scene?.removeFromParent()
        //skView.removeFromSuperview() // CAUSES BLACK SCREEN
    }

}
```

When the game ends, I call func gameEnd() which toggles the myviewbool variable and recalls goGame().  Any help is much appreciated!  ;-)

```
func gameEnded()
{
    if myviewbool == 0
    {
        myviewbool = 1
    }
    else
    {
        myviewbool = 0
    }
    isGamePlaying = false
    goGame()

}
```

Eventually I get memory warnings... then the app crashes.

Comment: BTW: I am toggling two views because I assumed this would solve my memory problems.  But the same result as using 1 view. :(

Comment: We need more info here,  the best thing you can do right now, is override deinit in your gamescene class, and put in a print("Scene Deinit")  This will tell you if the scene is being removed.  If it isn't you may have something holding it like a block, timer, or notification handler

Comment: Thanks Knight!  Will try that!

Answer (score 0):

So after a ton of time spent trying to debug what was causing the memory issues, it ended up being the NSTimers.  Thank you KnightOfDragon for getting me on the right path.  Eventhough I would try to invalidate each timer before loading a new scene, the timers never unloaded and continued in the background.  The deinit function was never called and therefore the scene was never unloaded. The only solution I could get working was to not use NSTimers at all but use this custom class here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift

Hope this helps someone in the future.  This cost me easily 40 hours of work.  :(

Comment: You should use an `SKAction` or two instead